# Why would a two hour mp4 video file be 8 seconds longer in one player versus another?

Tags: video, time, format, mp4

I have an mp4 container video with these specs:

```
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0x102]: Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
```

When I open this file in Quicktime the total length of the video is 2:02:58.  When I open the EXACT same video in another player (e.g. Quicktime or VLC) the video length is 2:02:50, which is 8 seconds shorter.   If I start the video on the two different players at the same exact moment, it's initially in sync, but slowly the difference between the two grows (1 sec difference 15 minutes in, then 2 sec difference 25 minutes in, etc).  Can anyone explain why this is going on?

Comment: "When I open this file in QuickTime … When I open the EXACT same video in another player (e.g. Quicktime or VLC) ..."? Unless QuickTime is different to Quicktime, this doesn't appear to make sense. In any case, it's probably the Kennedy assassination and everyone knows the CIA has infiltrated video player companies to keep certain things secret :-)

Comment: Since the length ratio is exactly **60/59.94**, It doen't seem like a conspirative. It's probably related to the player's settings (like V-Sync settings).